# mysql how to add trigger on insert to delete the first 100 rows if the rows count was 500 or 500+

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, sql-insert

hello im new to mysql,

how to make a trigger on insert to check row count if it was 500 to delete the first 100 rows.

so the row count get back to 400 then add new 100 untill it reach 500 and when try to add new one the trigger delete the first 100

Please don't give me other options i just want to know this answer

Comment: This site works best when it's one question at a time. And note that 25 and 5 would illustrate your problem just as well as 500 and 100.

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger in the trigger..

Answer (score 1):

Why bother?  You can just have an auto-incrementing id and keep track of the most recent records.  For real performance, you can have an index on `(id desc)`.

Then, a query such as:

```
select t.*
from t
order by id desc
limit 500;
```

should be quite fast.

At your leisure, you can schedule a job -- say a weekly job -- that truncates the table to 400 or 500 rows if you really need to reduce the size of the table.  However, such a table is so small that it is hard to believe that size considerations are involved.

Comment: that's not what i asked for i said a trigger that run on every insert that check the total row count and if it is 500 + it delete the first 100 automatically .... and please be more specific about the codes